# Allow special character in URL like curly bracket?

Tags: 6, uri

Any idea how I can allow special characters like `curly braces` and `equal` `({}, =)`?

The IFBYPHONE analytics asked me to add this `?ibp-adgroup=Sample_Node_Title&ibp-keyword={keyword}&ibp-matchtype={matchtype}` in the URL after the node alias.

Ex: `http://mydomain.com/sample-node-title?ibp-adgroup=Sample_Node_Title&ibp-keyword={keyword}&ibp-matchtype={matchtype}`

But currently it is being displayed like this.

`http://mydomain.com/sample-node-title%3Fibp-adgroup%3DSample_Node_Title%2526ibp-keyword%3D%7Bkeyword%7D%2526ibp-matchtype%3D%7Bmatchtype%7D`

I just tried to add it in the URL Path Settings but the result is being converted to HEX character.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not seeing what should be the question exactly here. The tags suggest this has something to do with htaccess, analytics and advertisement. But there is no apparent clue where this URL is being displayed in this misformed format..

Comment: sorry for the confusion...for some reason the third party analytics we are using is requesting to modify the url to something to the format they provided

Comment: The analytics software is requesting this page? It seems like your analytics software is URL encoding your querystring and apparently not allowing any form of querystring. **Edit:** Please edit your initial question and complete it with more information, like the name of the analytics software, and where this misformation is being requested.

Comment: they ask me to append this ?ibp-adgroup=Sample_Node_Title&ibp-keyword={keyword}&ibp-matchtype={matchtype} after thw node alias

Comment: Obviously you have to replace {keyword} and {matchtype} without the curly braces.

Comment: @Pere...No I just talked to them via phone and they said I just need to replace only the `ibp-adgroup=NODE_TITLE`

Comment: @ninjascorner Ring them again - ask them if they know what url encoding is :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know these characters are being escaped as specified in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which is the proper way.

Comment: Not entirely... the `?` and `=` are perfectly sane characters in querystring format, these are being encoded as well, as seen in the questioners message. This question is horribly incomplete.

Comment: Probably the whole url was encoded when he added the curly brackets {}

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that your node's alias is a "path", this path can not / should not include any querystring parameters (eg. `?ibp-adgroup=Sample_Node_Title&ibp-keyword={keyword}&ibp-matchtype={matchtype}`).

The only thing I can think of, with the information you're supplying (without knowing what your IFBYPHONE analytics is doing), is that you are trying to catch if your website has been linked from a certain campaign. If that's the case you should not be using this URL in your Drupal installation but using that URL in something external. Then a Drupal module or other sort of implementation in your website should catch the querystring variables.

Can't give you more then this with the supplied info.

About the curly braces, I think those are only placeholders which you should replace.